# What is the best way for a lot of toggle forms

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the thing. I have 255 checkboxes in total that upon selecting open up a form.
Here is an example:

[image]

My initial approach was to toggle hidden forms with something like:

```js
$("#machine1").click(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(".containerTech").show();

    } else {
        $(".containerTech").hide();
    }
});
```

But, seeing the amount of forms, writing that 255 times just isn't right. Each form is slightly different. I'm no expert on JavaScript, I would really appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction on this.

Comment: Use a common selector like $("input[type='checkbox']") this will apply for all your checkboxes.

Comment: Find element by class, not by ID, and bind click event to all of them at ones

Comment: Also instead of click function, I'd prefer "change" function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/z08cL3hm/

**Tips:**

- Use a selector that's general.
- Organize your checkboxes and forms appropriately (For example, each form can be placed next to the associated checkbox).

```js
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) {
   $(this).next("form").toggle($(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Toggle takes in Boolean to control the visible state of the element.

Note: I'm using **change** listener so that the logic works fine when checkbox is activated from keypress as well.

Comment: As I said each form is sligthly different, that means there are uniqe hidden forms beneath each checkbox. Your example would just open up the same box on all checkbox inputs.

Comment: check my fiddle, it should help.